# Why isn't this pulling any data?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
require_once('inc/dbc1.php');
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=###;dbname=#####', $username, $password);
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$sth = $pdo->prepare('
    SELECT name
    FROM Department
    ;');
$sth->execute(array(
    $pID
));
?>
<div id="popup_name" class="popup_block">
    <h2 style="padding:0; margin:0;">Add a:</h2><br>
    <form action="inc/add_p_c_validate.php" method="post"> 
    Professor<input type="radio" name="addType" value="Professor" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;Course<input type="radio" name="addType" value="Course" /> 
    <br><br>Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br> 
    Department: <select id='deptName' name='deptName'>

    <select name="deptName">
    <?php
    while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {echo "<option>".$row['name']."</option>";}

    ?>
    </select>
```

It doesnt give any error, just doesnt show a dropdown with any 'option's in it. I've tried the query is phpmyadmin and it returns all the department names...

Output for Dropdown (nothing) : [image: dd]

Anyone?

Comment: Just a small impovement hint: if you don't use placeholders in query it is more handy to use `PDO::query()` instead of `PDO::prepare() + PDO::execute()`

Comment: @user700070: look at documentation?

Comment: @user700070 Just for curiosities sake, try `$data = $sth->fetchAll(); print_r($data);` and see if anything prints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Department: <select id='deptName' name='deptName'>
```

This first select, you didn't close it or provide any options. Delete this select first and the second select works.